# Visual Studio Code and Team Foundation Server

Tags: visualstudiocode

I want to use Team Foundation with Visual Studio Code. I have seen other posts about this but i am Still getting an error.

This is what i have done:

1. Downloaded the extensions

   - TFS(TFS Visual Studio Code Integration)
     I have Visual Studio 2017 hooked up to Team Foundation
   - Azure Repos
2. I went to File - Preferences - Settings - Under Work Spaces - TFS Configuration - Path to TFS Command Line Client added - "tfvc.location": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"

Please note I tried this without // and only used / as well.

If i right click on a class and click Team Foundation - It displays Options. I clicked add and/Or Open in Browser but I get an error of:
Error: spawn "tfvc.location": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe" ENOENT

I was able to get GIT as a source control open and running but i would prefer to use Team Foundation.

Comment: I don't see how Salesforce is involved here. This would seem to be a better fit over at [so].

Comment: There is a post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056972/how-to-connect-tfs-in-visual-studio-code) for doing this set up, it also has some links to more resources. 

I imagine this is likely on the very edge of what is on-topic for this site. I can see Salesforce teams wanting to use TFS as their source control and being limited to VSCode as the development tool of choice for Salesforce. But you will likely get more eyes on your question at StackOverflow or SuperUser from users more experienced with this setup.

Comment: Ok, i will check over there for this thanks